# App that broadcasts interests to those nearby

Tags: android, iphone-app

At a conference, there are large gatherings of people with vaguely the same interests. The biggest challenge is finding the needle in the haystack of someone with the more specific interests relevant to you. For example, being at a software conference and wanting to discuss blockchain technologies. The current low-tech way to accomplish this is to wear descriptive t-shirts.

Do apps exist that accomplish this? That allow your information (literally a picture of you and a list of interests) to be broadcasted to those around you (using blutooth with no data) and encourage people to walk up and talk to you (not encouraging messaging)? If not, is this because that type of data is too difficult to transmit over bluetooth?

I'm assuming one problem is the potential for abuse, but I'm sure this could be solved by:

1. Limiting the number of interests someone has
2. Limiting matches per day
3. Flagging abusive users